# Micro-Ros for Arduino-rpi pico multiple publishers issue

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, ros, raspberry-pi-pico, ros2

I'm unable to publish more than 2 topics per node on RPi-Pico with micro-Ros.

When I try to publish only 2 topics its works fine , but otherwise the agent is not recieving any data but can see the topic in `ros2 topic list` , when trying to "echo" the topics it has no data or freezes.

So my question is where did my code went wrong and how to publish multiple publishers in micro-ros?

Thanks ahead to all.

Here is the code

```
#include <micro_ros_arduino.h>

#include "pinout.h"
#include "motor.h"
#include <math.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <rcl/rcl.h>
#include <rcl/error_handling.h>
#include <rclc/rclc.h>
#include <rclc/executor.h>

#include <geometry_msgs/msg/twist.h>
#include <std_msgs/msg/float32.h>
#include <std_msgs/msg/int16.h>


#define RCCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){error_loop();}}
#define RCSOFTCHECK(fn) { rcl_ret_t temp_rc = fn; if((temp_rc != RCL_RET_OK)){}}

void error_loop(){
  while(1){
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, !digitalRead(LED_PIN));
    delay(100);
  }
}


// declare motors
Motor Motor_LF(motor_lf, dir_lf1, dir_lf2, true, LF_ENCODER_P, LF_ENCODER_N);
Motor Motor_LB(motor_lb, dir_lb1, dir_lb2, true, LB_ENCODER_P, LB_ENCODER_N);
Motor Motor_RF(motor_rf, dir_rf1, dir_rf2, true, RF_ENCODER_P, RF_ENCODER_N);
Motor Motor_RB(motor_rb, dir_rb1, dir_rb2, true, RB_ENCODER_P, RB_ENCODER_N);

//uROS declarations
rcl_node_t node;
rclc_support_t support;
rcl_allocator_t allocator;

//Declare uROS Pub/Sub
// Pub
rcl_publisher_t encLF_pub;
rcl_publisher_t encLB_pub;
rcl_publisher_t encRF_pub;
rcl_publisher_t encRB_pub;

std_msgs__msg__Int16 rpm_lf;
std_msgs__msg__Int16 rpm_lb;
std_msgs__msg__Int16 rpm_rf;
std_msgs__msg__Int16 rpm_rb;

rclc_executor_t executor_pub;
rclc_executor_t executor_pub2;
rcl_timer_t timer;



// Hardware interrupt handler functions

void cntEnc0() {
// cntEnc is activated if DigitalPin is going from LOW to HIGH
// Check pin to determine direction
    if(digitalRead(LF_ENCODER_N)==LOW) 
      Motor_LF.encoder.encoderCount++;
    else 
      Motor_LF.encoder.encoderCount--;
}
void cntEnc1() {
// cntEnc is activated if DigitalPin is going from LOW to HIGH
// Check pin to determine the direction
    if(digitalRead(LF_ENCODER_P)==LOW) 
      Motor_LF.encoder.encoderCount--;
    else 
      Motor_LF.encoder.encoderCount++;
}

void cntEnc2() {

    if(digitalRead(LB_ENCODER_N)==LOW) 
      Motor_LB.encoder.encoderCount++;
    else 
      Motor_LB.encoder.encoderCount--;
  
}
void cntEnc3() {

    if(digitalRead(LB_ENCODER_P)==LOW) 
      Motor_LB.encoder.encoderCount--;
    else 
      Motor_LB.encoder.encoderCount++;

}

void cntEnc4() {

    if(digitalRead(RF_ENCODER_N)==LOW) 
      Motor_RF.encoder.encoderCount++;
    else 
      Motor_RF.encoder.encoderCount--;
  
}
void cntEnc5() {

    if(digitalRead(RF_ENCODER_P)==LOW) 
      Motor_RF.encoder.encoderCount--;
    else 
      Motor_RF.encoder.encoderCount++;

}

void cntEnc6() {

    if(digitalRead(RB_ENCODER_N)==LOW) 
      Motor_RB.encoder.encoderCount++;
    else 
      Motor_RB.encoder.encoderCount--;
  
}
void cntEnc7() {
 
    if(digitalRead(RB_ENCODER_P)==LOW) 
      Motor_RB.encoder.encoderCount--;
    else 
      Motor_RB.encoder.encoderCount++;
}


// motion directions
float power_y = 0, power_x = 0, power_z = 0, alpha = 0;


void timer_callback(rcl_timer_t * timer, int64_t last_call_time)
{
  RCLC_UNUSED(last_call_time);
  if (timer != NULL) {
    RCSOFTCHECK(rcl_publish(&encLF_pub, &rpm_lf, NULL));
    RCSOFTCHECK(rcl_publish(&encLB_pub, &rpm_lb, NULL));
    RCSOFTCHECK(rcl_publish(&encRF_pub, &rpm_rf, NULL));
    RCSOFTCHECK(rcl_publish(&encRB_pub, &rpm_rb, NULL));
  
  }
}


void linear_y(float power){
  Motor_RF.drive(power);
  Motor_LF.drive(power);
  Motor_RB.drive(power);
  Motor_LB.drive(power);
}


void linear_x(float power){
  Motor_RF.drive(power);
  Motor_LF.drive(-power);
  Motor_RB.drive(-power);
  Motor_LB.drive(power);
}


void angular_z(float power){ //clockwise
  Motor_RF.drive(-power);
  Motor_LF.drive(power);
  Motor_RB.drive(-power);
  Motor_LB.drive(power);
}


//ROS functions
    

// Init hardware function
void setup() {
  
  // Start serial output 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  set_microros_transports();
  delay(2000);

  allocator = rcl_get_default_allocator();
  
  // Setup hardware interrupt pins for encoder sensors
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(LF_ENCODER_P), cntEnc0, RISING);   //Hardware interrupt pin 1 for encoder 
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(LF_ENCODER_N), cntEnc1, RISING);   //Hardware interrupt pin 2 for encoder 

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(LB_ENCODER_P), cntEnc2, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(LB_ENCODER_N), cntEnc3, RISING);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(RF_ENCODER_P), cntEnc4, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(RF_ENCODER_N), cntEnc5, RISING);

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(RB_ENCODER_P), cntEnc6, RISING);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(RB_ENCODER_N), cntEnc7, RISING);


  //create init_options
  RCCHECK(rclc_support_init(&support, 0, NULL, &allocator));

  // create node
  RCCHECK(rclc_node_init_default(&node, "skateNode", "", &support));

  // create publishers
  RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(
    &encLF_pub,
    &node,
    ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, Int16),
    "rpm_lf_pub"));

  RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(
    &encLB_pub,
    &node,
    ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, Int16),
    "rpm_lb_pub"));

  RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(
    &encRF_pub,
    &node,
    ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, Int16),
    "rpm_rf_pub"));

  RCCHECK(rclc_publisher_init_default(
    &encRB_pub,
    &node,
    ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, Int16),
    "rpm_rb_pub"));

  // // create executor

  const unsigned int timer_timeout = 100;
  RCCHECK(rclc_timer_init_default(
            &timer,
            &support,
            RCL_MS_TO_NS(timer_timeout),
            timer_callback));
  
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_init(&executor_pub, &support.context, 1, &allocator));
  RCCHECK(rclc_executor_add_timer(&executor_pub, &timer));

  
  rpm_lf.data = Motor_LF.encoder.rpm;
  rpm_lb.data = Motor_LB.encoder.rpm;
  rpm_rf.data = Motor_RF.encoder.rpm;
  rpm_rb.data = Motor_RB.encoder.rpm;

}



// Do stuff here
void loop() {
  
 // Driving functions
  if(power_x == 0 && power_z == 0 ){
    linear_y(power_y);
  }
  else if(power_y == 0 && power_z == 0){
    linear_x(power_x);  
  }
  else if(power_y == 0 && power_x == 0){
    angular_z(power_z);  
  }
  else {
    mixed_motion_xy(power_y , power_x);
  }
  
  RCSOFTCHECK(rclc_executor_spin_some(&executor_pub, RCL_MS_TO_NS(100)));
  // RCSOFTCHECK(rclc_executor_spin_some(&executor_pub2, RCL_MS_TO_NS(100)));
  delay(50);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My was a bit different - do not see more than 2 topics at all.
from my arduino rp2040 I was trying to create 3 pubs and 1 sub.
but 'ros2 topic list' shows me two pubs created only.

investigating the problem, I found that arduino is defined as verylowmem profile while compiling micro-ros library, hence the settings are:

```
"rmw_microxrcedds": {
    "cmake-args": [
    "-DRMW_UXRCE_MAX_NODES=1",
    "-DRMW_UXRCE_MAX_PUBLISHERS=2",
    "-DRMW_UXRCE_MAX_SUBSCRIPTIONS=1",
    "-DRMW_UXRCE_MAX_SERVICES=0",
    "-DRMW_UXRCE_MAX_CLIENTS=1",
    "-DRMW_UXRCE_MAX_HISTORY=1",
    "-DRMW_UXRCE_TRANSPORT=custom"
    ]
}
```

the default settings are defined in extras/library_generation/colcon_verylowmem.meta

you can find more about configuration for memory constrained devices here
https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/advanced/microxrcedds_rmw_configuration/

**UPDATE:** I recompiled the library using lowmem settings for cortex_m0 and now it allows to create up to 10 pubs. So far, I don't see any issues with my setup of 3 pubs and 1 sub.
If you want to play around with the settings - you may need to re-compile the library too. here is the instruction:
https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/tree/main#how-to-build-the-precompiled-library

more details on library recompilation (mostly follow the process described on the micro-ros-arduino project):
okay. let me put some more details.

1. clone the microro repo
   git clone https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino.git
   and cd to the cloned folder, make sure that git branch is 'humble'
2. pull the builder docker image
   docker pull microros/micro_ros_static_library_builder:humble
   humble is is the latest up-to-date release of ROS2
3. modify the following line in the lib generation script:

````
diff --git a/extras/library_generation/library_generation.sh b/extras/library_generation/library_generation.sh
index 29c8ead..ef7e71a 100755
--- a/extras/library_generation/library_generation.sh
+++ b/extras/library_generation/library_generation.sh
@@ -76,7 +76,7 @@ if [[ " ${PLATFORMS[@]} " =~ " cortex_m0 " ]]; then
rm -rf firmware/build

export TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=/uros_ws/gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2017-q4-major/bin/arm-none-eabi-
-    ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_firmware.sh /project/extras/library_generation/cortex_m0_toolchain.cmake /project/extras/library_generation/colcon_verylowmem.meta
+    ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_firmware.sh /project/extras/library_generation/cortex_m0_toolchain.cmake /project/extras/library_generation/colcon_lowmem.meta

find firmware/build/include/ -name "*.c"  -delete
cp -R firmware/build/include/* /project/src/```
````

I believe there is a better way to tell library to compile with lowmem profile for context_m0, but I directly modified the build script.

4. start building the library using the pulled docker image
   docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/project --env MICROROS_LIBRARY_FOLDER=extras microros/micro_ros_static_library_builder:humble

this step will take a while, relax and wait.

After the build is done, you may have up to 10 pubs on your rp2040

Comment: Hi , thanks for replying .I'll try to implement it and update you if i succeed.

Comment: Can you please guide me with the compilation? Having an issue with stderr .Did what was written but with no luck

Comment: okay. let me put some more details.

Comment: I added more details in the answer as the comments are limited in length.
I've never had stderr exceptions while compiling the library, can you please provide more details about the error if you still have problems recompiling the library.

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks alot for the detalied answer .